# Can process.hrtime() be used cross machines?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to measure the time of a job waiting in job queue, so I thought I can add a start time to the job data:

```
addToQueue({
  queueTime: process.hrtime()
})
```

and in the consumer I can get the `queueTime` and use `process.hrtime(queueTime)` to get the time cost.

But I'm not sure if `process.hrtime` can be used cross machines?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless they have synchronized clocks, but even then I would not trust it for the kind of resolution that `process.hrtime` provides.

Comment: If the resolution I need is microsecond, there is no need to use `process.hrtime` right?

Comment: You won't get microsecond resolution without `process.hrtime`.

Comment: isn't `+(new Date)` microsecond resolution?

Comment: No, JavaScript Dates have millisecond resolution.

Comment: sorry my bad, I meant millisecond